# Example Highcharts in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, highcharts, ionic4

I'm trying to add to my ionic4 project High-charts  (https://www.highcharts.com/)

with this tutorial
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/setting-chart-ionic-app-using-highcharts/

Doing it, I get this error can someone help me pls

***ionic info***

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (C:\****\*****\*****\*****\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.8
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

System:

   NodeJS : v11.10.0 (D:\*****\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.7.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

***package.json***

```
"highcharts": "^7.1.1",
```

**tab2page.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
            Tab Two
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <div id="container" style="display: block;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

**tab2page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    var myChart = HighCharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
      }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
      }]
    });
  }

}
```

**tab2.module.ts**

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Tab2Page } from './tab2.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab2Page }])
  ],
  declarations: [Tab2Page]
})
export class Tab2PageModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### Got this error on tab2.page.ts

```
{
    "resource": "/ionic/new/myApp/src/app/tab2/tab2.page.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2322",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type '{ name: string; data: number[]; }' is not assignable to type 'SeriesAbandsOptions | SeriesAdOptions | SeriesAoOptions | SeriesApoOptions | SeriesAreaOptions | SeriesArearangeOptions | SeriesAreasplineOptions | SeriesAreasplinerangeOptions | ... 88 more ... | SeriesZigzagOptions'.\n  Property 'type' is missing in type '{ name: string; data: number[]; }' but required in type 'SeriesZigzagOptions'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 30,
    "startColumn": 16,
    "endLineNumber": 33,
    "endColumn": 8,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 249559,
            "startColumn": 5,
            "endLineNumber": 249559,
            "endColumn": 9,
            "message": "'type' is declared here.",
            "resource": "/ionic/new/myApp/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts"
        }
    ]
}
```

Image from error:

[image]
<sub>(source: [imgbbb.com](https://imgbbb.com/images/2019/04/28/image6cf8b877b91c1a31.png))</sub>

Comment: can you try adding plot options to your chart? something like `plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },` before or after `series:`

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the type for each series or set `type = undefined`:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  var myChart = HighCharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Fruit eaten'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Jane',
      type: undefined,
      data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
      name: 'John',
      type: undefined,
      data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
  });
}
```

---

The better solution is to use `highcharts-angular` official Highcharts wrapper for Angular. It can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular.

**home.page.html:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <div>
      <highcharts-chart
        style="margin: 30px;"
        [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
        [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
        [options]="chartOptions"
        [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
        [(update)]="updateFlag"
        [runOutsideAngular]="runOutsideAngularFlag"
      ></highcharts-chart>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  chart;
  updateFromInput = false;
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = 'chart';
  chartCallback;
  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Fruit eaten'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Jane',
      data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
      name: 'John',
      data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
  };

  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    this.chartCallback = chart => {
      self.chart = chart;
    };
  }
}
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HighchartsChartModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Comment: This is a great example for getting _Highcharts_ to work on an Ionic page. It would also be helpful to show an example of implementing it on the component level. Am in the process of trying that now...

Comment: It works just fine in a component as well, just making sure to bring in that `HighchartsChartModule` in the imports of `components.module.ts`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I leave the code waiting for it to work. Now the problem I have is that the graph does not fit the device. I wait your answer

```html
  this.chartOptions = HighCharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      backgroundColor: '#E6ECF3',
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Fruit eaten'
      }
    },
    colors: ['#086d54', '#097f62', '#0b9270', '#0ca47e', '#0db68c', '#0fc89a', '#10dba8', '#11edb7'],
    series: [{
        name: 'test',
        data: [{
          name: 'Parte 1',
          y: 61.41
        }, {
            name: 'Parte 2',
            y: 11.84
        },{
          name: 'Chrome',
          y: 61.41
        }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
        }],
        type: undefined
      }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as any after option object of charts (cast it to any)
like this

```
<pre>
   this.chartOptions = HighCharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      backgroundColor: '#E6ECF3',
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Fruit eaten'
      }
    },
    colors: ['#086d54', '#097f62', '#0b9270', '#0ca47e', '#0db68c', '#0fc89a', '#10dba8', '#11edb7'],
    series: [{
        name: 'test',
        data: [{
          name: 'Parte 1',
          y: 61.41
        }, {
            name: 'Parte 2',
            y: 11.84
        },{
          name: 'Chrome',
          y: 61.41
        }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
        }]
      }]
    } as any);
</pre>
```